# Gamma Frailty Cox survival model using survey data

Tags: r, mixed-models, survey, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I need to run a multilevel analysis (on two levels) using Cox frailty survival model on a survey data. My problem is how to write the design weight using the two weights needed and apply them to the analysis.

I have identified the needed variables for the survey design, which are :

```
psu/cluster=~v021
individual-level weight=~wt1_1
cluster-level weigh=~wt2_1
strata/stratum=~v022
```

Please can someone help me with the svydesign code and how to include it and the weights in a model.

To view the minimum reproducible data:
`datapasta::df_paste (head(rcom2018, 10)[, c('pid', 'study_time', 'died', 'v021', 'v022', 'wt2_1', 'wt1_1', 'v024', 'v025', 'mat_edu')])`

For instance, how do I account for the 2 weights in the gamma frailty model below?

`Frailty1 <- coxph (Surv(study_time, died) ~ factor(v024) + factor(mat_edu) + v025 + frailty(v021,distribution="gamma"), data=rcom2018)`

```r
library(survey)
#> Warning: package 'survey' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Warning: package 'survival' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survey'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     dotchart
library(survival)


rcom1 <- data.frame(
                         pid = c(1,2,3,4,
                                 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
                                 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
                                 30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
                                 41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50),
                  study_time = c(13,9,17,
                                 31,39,22,24,0,23,12,9,35,18,20,60,
                                 18,5,46,26,54,37,51,31,55,27,15,39,6,
                                 29,0,9,40,23,12,35,56,14,40,57,42,
                                 5,42,39,39,54,19,52,42,7,28),
                        died = c(0,0,0,0,
                                 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                        v021 = c(1,1,1,1,
                                 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,
                                 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,
                                 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4),
                        v022 = c("1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1"),
                        v012 = c(40,37,27,
                                 27,24,32,35,35,34,20,28,28,26,24,24,
                                 25,26,26,26,26,28,27,25,25,27,26,
                                 26,21,21,31,36,36,27,23,32,32,33,33,
                                 33,28,25,37,33,34,33,28,28,29,33,33),
                       wt2_1 = c(401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,
                                 401.200012207031,401.200012207031,401.200012207031),
                       wt1_1 = c(2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,
                                 2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,
                                 2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,
                                 2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,
                                 2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,2.5074667930603,
                                 2.5074667930603,5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,5.1194109916687,
                                 5.1194109916687,2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,
                                 2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,
                                 2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,
                                 2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,
                                 2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,2.40910983085632,
                                 2.40910983085632,1.06203985214233,
                                 1.06203985214233),
                        v024 = c("1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1"),
                        v025 = c("1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                                 "1"),
                     mat_edu = c("5","5",
                                 "5","4","4","5","4","4","4","4","4","4",
                                 "5","5","5","5","5","5","4","4","5",
                                 "4","4","4","5","3","3","4","4","5",
                                 "5","5","5","4","2","2","0","0","0","5",
                                 "5","0","1","5","5","3","3","5","5",
                                 "5")
                )

Frailty1 <- coxph (Surv(study_time, died) ~ factor(v024) + factor(mat_edu) + v025 + frailty(v021,distribution="gamma"), data=rcom1)
#> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm assuming that you have more data that what is present in this example. I think the example if probably too small to satisfy the needs of the mathematical machinery as it stands. Furthermore there is no `v012` column in the example data. Please read the error messages and fix the things that they tell you need to be fixed.

Comment: Hi IRTFM, thanks for your response. I'm new in R and I don't understand the error message. I've tried to re-run it but it keeps coming back as such. I've also added more data in the example, hopefully it will help. Thanks

Comment: Is that data.frame object supposed to be assigned to the name `rcom2018`? At the moment you are getting errors that suggest a failure to create the data object you hope to work with. (I get a different error after making that assignment.)

Comment: I have reassigned it to the object `Frailty` and it executed successfully but when I paste it here it brings up the error message. I have both `rcom2018` and `Frailty1` in my R-studio.

Comment: You may have `rcom2018` but at the moment your code is assigning the data.frame to `rcom1` and the error message says you do NOT have it in a location where the coxph function can find it. If you are getting the error you claim, then you should not have `Frailty1` since it is supposed to be created by code that is throwing an error. You should see if the error messages you posted earlier are still present when you fix an the errors that were identified in your earlier postings. Then use the [edit] facilities to make the body of this question sensilble. At the moment it is not.

Comment: Hello, I think I have corrected the error, can you check please. Although, the example is not large enough to produce contrasts for the factor variables, as it's a large dataset.

Comment: At the moment you cannot even get `coxph` to run. (Seems you should remove the terms for which the variables are constant.) But your question title and text body appear to be about package:survey for which you have offered no code or even loaded. Voting to close as needing further details.

Comment: You need to use `survey::svycoxph` instead of `coxph`. You also need to define your survey design with `survey::svydesign()`. You should be able to calculate your overall weight by multiplying `wt1_1 * wt2_1`.

Comment: I know I need to use `svycoxph`, but I don't know how to define the survey design and include the weights in my analysis. That's what the body of my question is. I have identified the needed variables for the survey design, which are; psu/cluster=~v021, individual-level weight=~wt1_1, cluster-level weigh=~wt2_1 ,strata/stratum=~v022.

Please can someone help me with the svydesign code and how to include it and the weights in a frailty model.